# How to get item position from multiple (5) spinners immediately after only one was clicked on

Tags: android, spinner

For my calculation I need the position of all 5 spinners immediately after only one spinner was ckicked on. I saw more examples ( OnClickListeners) how to get the item position from a single 1 clicked spinner, but I don´t know how to get the item position from additional 4 not clicked spinners.

I don´t want to relay on a history of how they were set in the past.

The question is: How to get the item position from all spinners at once, if only one was clicked on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

spinner1.getSelectedItem()
spinner2.getSelectedItem().. and so on.

Comment: It seems good. Is there any way to substitute the 5 OnItemSelectedListener() on 5 spinners by only common one? The position will be getted individually after that, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There is also

```
spinner1.getSelectedItemId()
spinner2.getSelectedItemId().. and so on.
```

Comment: It seems good. Is there any way to substitute the 5 OnItemSelectedListener() on 5 spinners by only common one? The position will be getted individually after that, as you suggested.